# T-SQL: How to count records that fall within given date range?

Tags: t-sql

I have a table that has among other columns, effective and expiration date. Given the date range, I need to count how many are active for each month within that date range.  Any ideas how to do this?

Edit:
It seems that many are missing the point of the question. It is not a simple where query. I have records that have different effective and expiration dates. I want to run a query, that given the date range, it returns me the count, for each month within the given range, number of records. So if I give it date range from august 2012 - august 2013, it needs to give me for each month, record that where active based on therr effective and expiration date.

An example of the data

```
EffDt          ExpDt        Id
08/01/2012     10/01/2012   1
08/01/2012     09/31/2012   2
10/01/2012     01/01/2013   3
11/01/2012     08/01/2013   4
01/01/2013     09/01/2013   5

if the date range is  07/01/2012 - 05/01/2013 I should get

Date         Count
07-2012      0        - there are  no active records in 07-2012
08-2012      2        - id 1 and 2 are active in 08-2012
09-2012      2        - id 1,2 are active in 09-2012
10-2012      2        - id 1,3 are active but 2 is no longer active in 10-2012
11-2012      3        - id 1,3,4 are now active, 2 is not longer active
12-2012      3
01-2013      4
02-2013      3        - id 3 is now no longer active
03-2013      3
04-2013      3
05-2013      3
```

Comment: You mean given current month you need to know whether it fallse `BETWEEN` 2 dates?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is it trolling? How can a preson with 5K reputation ask these kinds of questions?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: Your question does sound plausible, but a quick look into the profile reveals that the 5K may have been earned in a very different area of expertise.

Comment: I am no sql expert, hence I am asking a question. I can get the basic to intermediate stuff in SQL done, but with this I don't know even where to begin, and I do not have a time to study sql in depth. I need a pointer, if you cannot give it so be it, vote to delete.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: Why would it be trolling, it is like asking somebody who speaks German, why is he asking questions about Japanese. I mean...

Comment: @epitka I apologize, no offence meant. It's just when a Dev has knowlege of technologies such as .NET, ASP.NET, certain degree of familiarity with databases is assumed.

Comment: @epitka: To be honest, your question did look like a "read the manuals" one, until you clarified the problem. So, no-one was actually missing the point, it was your question that was missing vital info. And I think you could further improve the question by adding a simple example illustrating what you are trying to achieve (a data sample and the expected result). I do have an idea about what is being asked but the example would really help me to be sure about it.

Comment: @epitka Posting your table structure, some sample data and the desired result would help considerably in answering the question.  And it would have also shown any complexity that wasn't initially apparent from your original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way for you to get this result would be to create a calendar table with dates, then you can join the calendar table to your current table to determine what falls in the date range.

If you don't have a calendar table, then you can use a recursive CTE to generate the list of dates:

```
;with cte (dt) as
(
  select cast('2012-07-01' as date)
  union all
  select dateadd(m, 1, dt)
  from cte
  where dateadd(m, 1, dt) <= '2013-05-01'
)
select dt
from cte
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce585/14).

You can use this CTE an join to your table and get the count for each row in the range:

```
;with cte (dt) as
(
  select cast('2012-07-01' as date)
  union all
  select dateadd(m, 1, dt)
  from cte
  where dateadd(m, 1, dt) <= '2013-05-01'
)
select c.dt, count(t.id) TotalCount
from cte c
left join yourtable t
  on c.dt >= t.effdt 
  and c.dt <= t.expdt
group by c.dt
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce585/12)